# Display UIAlertView when UIBarButtonItem is pressed

Tags: ios, uialertview, uibarbuttonitem

I have a UIBarButtonItem and I want to display an UIAlertView when it is pressed.

I have tried an IBAction, adding a gesture, etc. and haven't found a good solution. 
Any ideas?

I tried this:

```
-(IBAction)helpButton:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender{
    NSString* title;
    NSString* message;
    NSString* yesButtonText;
    NSString* noButtonText;

    tutorialAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title 
        message:message 
        delegate:self 
        cancelButtonTitle:nil 
        otherButtonTitles:yesButtonText, noButtonText, nil];

    tutorialAlertView.delegate = self;
    [tutorialAlertView show];
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by a good solution? And what is the issue you encountered?

Comment: None of the things I have tried have worked. Adding a gesture caused it to crash, IBAction didn't work at all, etc.

Comment: What is the crash message when you use IBAction? You do not need to add gesture since there is built-in tap gesture recognizer for button.

Comment: And try to post your existing code.

Comment: I posted the existing code above

Comment: Alright, any error message using the code above?

Comment: The way you're doing it right now is the best way to do it. What kind of solution were you looking for?

Comment: @Scott It doesn't work! I put a break point and it isn't getting called. I hooked it up right and everything, I read somewhere that UIbarbutton items can't send actions, is that the problem?

Comment: @verbumdei There is no error message either

Comment: Have you linked the IBAction to your bar button item in your storyboard or interface builder?

Comment: @verbumdei Yes I linked it

Comment: If you know it isn't getting called, then you **didn't** hook it up right.  Edit your post to explain how you hooked it up.

Comment: @robmayoff I clicked and dragged in the sent actions portion of the uibarbuttonitem's connections inspector in the interface builder and selected the action "helpButton:". This is how I have connected all IBActions, is it somehow different for uibarbuttonitems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following and now it works:

```
helpButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Help" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(helpButton:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = helpButton;
```

Answer (score -1):

You declared delegate = self twice, try to remove the other one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I removed the double delegate declaration and it still isn't getting called.